# Get list of certain field back

Tags: linq

I can't get the syntax right when fiddling around with this.  I want only the list of UserIds after the removal.

```
List<int> unselectedHockeyPlayers = allHockeyPlayers.Where(u => hockeyPlayers.Contains(u.UserId)).ToList());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the projection to the `UserId`s.

```
List<int> unselectedHockeyPlayers = allHockeyPlayers
    .Where(u => !hockeyPlayers.Contains(u.UserId))
    .Select(u => u.UserId)
    .ToList()
```

Or more succinctly,

```
List<int> unselectedHockeyPlayers = allHockeyPlayers
    .Select(u => u.UserId)
    .Except(hockeyPlayers)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The ToList() must be at the end.

```
List<int> unselectedHockeyPlayers = allHockeyPlayers.Where(u => hockeyPlayers.Contains(u.UserId))).Select(u => u.UserId).ToList();
```

EDIT: You also have to select specifically the field you want with the .Select() clause. Otherwise, you'll get a List